# Adobe Acrobat PDF custom calculation

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I kept getting error which is reference not defined. I am entering this script in custom calculation section. Also it kept saying that I am missing semicolon before the statement.

```
var nPrice = this.getField(sub).value;
var nPrice1 = this.getField(sub1).value;
var nPrice2 = this.getField(sub2).value;

var nDiscount = this.getField(discount).value;

var total = (nPrice + nPrice1 + nPrice2) * nDiscount;

event.value = total;
```

Comment: If `sub` is the *name* of your field, should it not then be in quotes?

Comment: Now I feel dumb... Yes, you are correct, it should be in quotes. Thank you for pointing out an obvious mistake when I could not see it.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned already in a comment, the field names must be between quotes. Without quotes, the argument of `getField()` is expected to be a variable (and if it has not been defined, you have the reference error).

Actually, all the variables could be left away, and instead of that one single (long) line of code could be written.

Comment: Yes, field names should be in quotes. Thank you. I managed to get the calculation I wanted for the invoice.